# Почему нет исключения TypeError?

Tags: python

```
def is_numbers(iterable):
    """Проверить все ли элементы в iterable есть числа."""
    if iterable:
        return all(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float, complex)), iterable))
    else:
        return False
```

Если передаем просто число, то генерируется исключение TypeError:

```
>>> is_numbers(131)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    is_numbers(131)
  File "/home/dzmitry/iterchk.py", line 23, in is_numbers
    return all(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float, complex)), iterable))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>>
```

Но если передаем None, то функция возвращает False:

```
>>> is_numbers(None)
False
>>>
```

Почему так получается?

Ведь None вроде как тоже не iterable:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable

```
try:
    none_iterator = iter(None)
except TypeError:
    print(None, 'is not iterable')

None is not iterable
>>>
```

Comment: Аааа, все, я понял! Спасибо! Сделайте ответом и я помечу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все происходит так, как вы задали в коде: передаете `None` - срабатывает вторая ветка (`else`), которая возвращает `False`:

```
# на вход (iterable) подаем None
def is_numbers(iterable):
    if iterable:    # здесь условие получает None
        return all(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float, complex)), iterable))
    else:
        # соответственно выполняется эта ветка
        # и возвращается False
        return False
```